# How to read the payload of a Firebase Cloud Messaging notification?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send data notifications to other users. I'm sending a json similar to this:

```
    {
  "message":{
    "to":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    },
    "data" : {
      "type" : "MSG",
      "id" : "abcdefg123456...."
    }
  }
}
```

And this code to receive notifications:

```
    class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
        override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {

            remoteMessage.notification?.let { notificacao ->

             //How to read payload?

                enviarNotificacao(notificacao.title ?: "", notificacao.body ?: "")
            }
        }
```

How do I read the data contained in "id" and "type"?

Answer (score 0):

The `id` and `type` are both inside a data payload, to be able to read these values then try the following:

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "From: ${remoteMessage.from}")

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty().let {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.data)

    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    remoteMessage.notification?.let {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: ${it.body}")
    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}
```

`remoteMessage.data` will contain both the `id` and `type`

Check here for more info:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Answer (score 0):

You can send data this way :

```
{
  "to": "wOAT...",
  "data": {
    "title": "Notification title",
    "message": "Notification message",
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2",
    "key3" : "value3"
   }
}
```

and fetch data this way :

**MyFirebaseMessagingService**

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {
        val data = p0.data
        val title = data["title"]
        val message = data["message"]
        val key1= data["value1"]
        val key2= data["value2"]
        val key3= data["value3"]

        showNotification(title, message, ...)
    }
}
```